# Why is my Loftwing not coming when I whistle for it?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have already got to the deep woods in Zelda: Skyward Sword but my son decided to use the bird statue to return to the sky in the middle of the quest.

Now I can't get back down to the woods.  If I throw myself off the edge in the sky and press down, the Loftwing doesn't collect me. How can I return to Faron Woods?

Comment: Just to clarify: You returned to the sky, hopped on the Loftwing, flew to Skyloft – but now the Loftwing doesn't appear when you whistle after jumping off one of the piers?

Comment: I'm having the same problem-I jump off the wooden piers, but I just hang there, and if I let go I get the annoying knight lecture!

Comment: You know you have to press down on the D-pad while Link's in the air, right? If he's just dangling from the edge, you didn't approach the edge with enough speed.

Comment: Hi, Dene, and welcome to gaming. This doesn't answer the question, so would be better served as a comment. I'm going to convert this over for you.

Answer (score 13):

Link may only leave Skyloft under 2 conditions:

1. It must be daytime. Only graduates of the Academy are allowed to fly at night; attempting to skydive at night results in the annoying lecture from the Rescue Knight.
2. Link may only skydive from designated points (usually wooden piers) in Skyloft; falling off anywhere else does not cause him to assume the skydiving posture, and results in the annoying lecture from the Rescue Knight.

Answer (score 8):

You have to *dash* off the piers. If you don't dash you'll dangle off and you fall off, not dive off. If you are trying to fly at night, as other comments say, you cannot call your Loftwing. One more thing - you have to dive back into Faron Woods, your Loftwing can't fly down with you.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I think of off the top of my head is: Is it night?

If it is, Loftwings don't fly at night. Take a nap in any bed until morning and try again.

Answer (score 1):

There are only certain places you can leave Skyloft from, these are marked by wooden piers.

You can tell if you are allowed to call your loftwing if Link skydives off the platform rather than just falling.

Answer (score -1):

Hold A to dash as you approach the end of the wooden pier and Link will jump instead of dangle from the end.  He has to jump before you can press down on the directional pad to call your bird.

Comment: This was answered 5 years ago with the same thing. Your answer does not add anything new.